# Cell Info of a Table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the cell information of a table row. So a user clicks on any cell and the value of the clicked cell as well as other cells in that row must be printed

```
$("#target tbody").on("click", "td", function (e) {
    // $(e.target).closest()??
    //console.log(all cell values in that row)
});
```

Can anybody look at this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find)

[.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
$("#target tbody").on("click", "td", function (e) {
  var val = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').map(function(){
     return $(this).text();
  }).get().join();
  console.log(val);
});
```